# Recreate Adobe Portfolio Dual Hover Effect On Image & Text Block

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

ive been trying to recreate the hover dual effect that is on https://andreas-demo.myportfolio.com/

However i cant seem to get both to align correctly and then i cannot get the affect that hovers over the entire section but that changes BOTH: 1- Darkening the image, 2 -inversing the colors.

I want to be able to get both affects to happen while hovering over the entire block, just like on the site above^.

Here's my code;

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  !important;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}

a img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(60%);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.media {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  !important;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="">
    <div class="media">
      <img src="img/pexels-photo-733438.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      <p>PROJECT 1</p>
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On container:hover, set your container'background-color as black (default to white) and set the image opacity as 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `:hover` pseudo-class to one of the 3 parent (wrapper) elements -
 `.container`, `.container > a`, or `.media` element. This will have the effect of adding the overlay to both elements on `:hover`.

Like this:

```css
.container {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}


.container__link {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.media {
  flex: 6;
  background-color: #222222;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.container:hover .media img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}


.description {
  flex: 4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #222222;
}

.container:hover .description {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #ffffff;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="" class="container__link">
    <div class="media">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>PROJECT 1</p>
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get my text to align in the miiddle beside the image.. vertical align doesnt seem to work :/

Comment: I updated my solution to use `display: flex`, which makes the vertical alignment a lot easier. As well as reorganized the layout to make the transitions more closely match the desired result.